# Passing Value Between 3 Different Screens (2 Bottom Sheet + 1 Screen) Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm currently trying to pass value between 3 Screens:

- Home Screen
- Choose House Bottom Sheet
- Create Ticket Bottom Sheet

So the behavior is in my home screen I have a FAB which on tapped will open the Choose House Bottom Sheet, this BS is used to display all of the house and when 1 of the house is tapped it will take user to take picture from reusable camera page. After taking picture it will pass the picture value to the create ticket Bottom Sheet and we can fill in other information about the ticketing and we can create the ticket.

My Problem is I want to passed a value to the Home Screen that indicates the Ticket is already created and from there I want to do some operation like animate a tab index

But something is wrong with my code about passing the value.

Here's Some code Snippet:

Home Screen FAB on Tap function

```
onTap: () async {
  // bool scrollToTemuan =
  //     await ReusableCreateTemuanBottomSheet
  //         .buildModalBottom(
  //             context: context,
  //             onSolveFindingFunction: () {
  //               setState(() {
  //                 findingPaginationNeedRebuildCounter++;
  //                 solvingPaginationNeedRebuildCounter++;
  //               });
  //             });

  /// navigate to choose temuan location bottom sheet
  bool isTicketCreated = await ChooseTemuanLocationBottomSheet.buildModalBottom(
      context: context,
      userLocationJoined: organizationLocationList,
      source: 'homepage',
      onOptionSelected: (Map<dynamic, dynamic> value) {});

  if(isTicketCreated == true){
    tabController.animateTo(1);
  }
  setState(() {});
},
```

Choose House Bottom Sheet Code:

```
bool isTicketCreated = false

onTap: () {
  ///Select the House
  setState(() {
    onOptionSelected(selectedOption);

    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => TakePicturePage(
            locationName: locationName,
          ),
        )).then((value) {
      if (value != null) async {
        _originalImageFile = value as File;
        setState(() {});
        Navigator.pop(context);

        /// after picture taken, pass picture and selected house data to create temuan
        /// And later on we will change the bool value depending on the ticket created or not
        isTicketCreated = await ReusableCreateTemuanBottomSheet
            .buildModalBottom(
          context: context,
          imageFile: _originalImageFile,
          userLocationJoined:
          userLocationJoined,
          selectedLocationData: selectedOption,
        );
      }
    });
  });
},
```

Create Ticket Bottom Sheet Code:

```
 onTap: () async {
      DateTime? deadline;
      if (pickedDate != null) {
        setState2(() {
          isLoading2 = true;
          isTicketCreated = true;
        });
      }
      
        await ProfileDatabase.createTemuan(
          temuanTitle: temuanTitle,
          temuanDescription: _textControllerDescription.text,
          temuanLocation: _selectedLocationValue as String,
          temuanLocationId: _selectedLocationId as String,
        ).then((value) {
          setLoading(true);
          Navigator.popUntil(
              context2,
              ModalRoute.withName(HomePage.id));
          ReusableSnackBar.buildSnackBar(
              context2,
              'Berhasil menyimpan temuan',
              backgroundColor: successBackgroundColor,
              messageColor: primaryText,
          );
        });
    },
```

So What I expect Is When I finished creating the ticket each bottom sheet will update each other until it got passed to the home page. When I ran the code the Create Ticket Bottom Sheet return true but when it got passed to the choose house bottom sheet it returned false to the home page.

I think the problem is with the Navigator.pop got triggered so it return the default value which is false

Any Idea ? Thanks before

Comment: using `Navigator.popUntil(` in you last stage is not good practice. its better to dissmiss bottomsheet and return the value. based on your code, you have to understand the widget tree. For example:  if `home` is stem, `house` is branch and `ticket` is leaf,  im not sure you can jump from leaf to the stem.

Comment: to return value, use `Navigator.pop(context, yourReturnedValue)`.